# dot length in java - finding its definition

Tags: java, arrays

In which class is the `length` field defined in Java (e.g. for array length)?
Will I be able to see it defined say in `Object` class?

EDIT : Why was this field so designed(any thing related with security or memory efficiency)?

Comment: Are we talking String length, array length, object size, or what?

Comment: @Jason: I think he's talking about the arrays.

Comment: @Jason, i think he is talking about array.length, String doesn't have a length variable, it has length() method (which is confusing since its not getLength()).

Comment: That was what I assumed.

Comment: Probably best not to assume; the lack of String.length could be the reason he's asking, too.

Comment: Well we all know what happens when you assume. You are probably right, I guess know one will know until he clarifies.

Comment: @Lord isn't assuming things a big part of developers work? i assume

Comment: @medopal: Absolutely not!  Assumptions about requirements lead to customers saying "what's this for"/"why doesn't it do that", which is the first step in the path to project failure and developer depression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Array types are special in Java. This is an excerpt from [JLS 10.7 Array Members](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.7)

> The members of an array type are all of the following:

- The `public final` field `length`, which contains the number of components of the array (length may be positive or zero).
- The `public` method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name in class `Object` and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the clone method of an array type `T[]` is `T[]`.
- All the members inherited from class Object; the only method of Object that is not inherited is its `clone` method.

Despite this, there are still old-standing bugs when you're using reflection on arrays: neither `length` nor `clone` could be found through reflection ([bug# 5047859](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5047859), [bug# 4987375](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4987375)).

Neither member is inherited in the traditional way from any superclass; all array types extends from `Object` directly. This "special treatment" is likely why these bugs exist in the first place.

---

"does this mean that never will one be able to see the length variable being defined?"

There is no actual source code for array types. Again, these types are special; the JVM just pulls out these types out of a hat whenever they're required. You will not see a `.java` source file for the array type `int[].class` (i.e. the type of all `int` array).

So, no, you will not be able to *see* the `length` *field* defined.

---

For further reading, here are some information on Java Reflection:

- [The Java Tutorials: Reflection API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/)
- [Advanced Language Topic technical article: Using Java Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

Comment: does this mean that never will one be able to see the length variable being defined?

Comment: i didn't understand 'could be found through reflection' phrase here could you please explain it?

Comment: @abson: I added some remarks to address your comments. Feel free to ask for more clarification.

Comment: @polygenelubricants could you please tell me the reason for such a special treatment for length field.

Comment: The special treatment is actually on array types as a whole. You can define arrays of any type of any dimension. `int[].class` is an array type, `int[][].class` is another array type, so is `Thing[].class` and `Stuff[][].class`. Java has to create these types on-demand as required; there is no source code for them.

Comment: @polygenelubricants thanks for your promptness if you don't mind could suggest a java book that deals with basics for me

Comment: I never studied Java from basics, so I don't know a good book for that. Eventually, however, you **MUST** read Josh Bloch's _Effective Java_.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays are not like regular classes, they are a special case defined in the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html). So the .length public final variable is defined in the Java Language Specification, but it is not actually defined anywhere in a .java or a .class file.

Comment: does this mean that it is defined in Object class?

Comment: +1 for beating me to the JLS link.  @abson, no, it is not in the Object class.  If you print out someArray.getclass(), you get something non-human-readable, it's a special type built into the language.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a bit more specific than that.

A variable length can exist in any class. If you mean from the API then you are probably looking for the Array.

Some classes have a length() method.

Comment: Some have a length property (like Arrays), some a length() method, like String, and others a size() method, like various collections.

Comment: Yes its the length property of arrays

Answer (score 2):

In java with arrays you can do this. For example:

```
String[] a = new String [] {"a","b","c"};
int length = a.length;
```

Length would be 3;

Comment: but he is asking where is the length var?

Comment: yes @jschoen could you tell me as to where length variable used in your program is defined?

Comment: As Yishai stated, it is not really defined in the way you are thinking. It is part of the language itself. Built in, if you will. So you will not find it in .java file. Maybe you are asking the wrong question. What is it you are trying to accomplish by tracking this down? Maybe we could be more help with that.

Comment: I didn't get this 'part of the language itself' line. Could @jschoen explain as to what this so called JLS is?

Comment: The JLS is the Java Language Specification. It is long, and honestly not a fun read, but is interesting. It essentially is a document explaining the details of the Java language, the standards, etc. It is defined should be used as a resource for you programming java.

Answer (score 1):

*Any* class can have a field called `length`. Just add it.

Arrays do not have a `length` field; they have something which *looks like* such a field:

```
int[] a = new int[10];
System.out.println("array length is: " + a.length);
```

but it is not *really* a plain field, because this does not compile:

```
int[] a = new int[10];
a.length = 42;  // <- here the compiler gets grumpy
```

and, at the JVM level, the array length is accessed with a specific opcode (`arraylength`) and not the generic instance field access opcode (`getfield`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer to this question.  Anyone can include a `length` variable in a class, but there's no guarantee that it exists -- or, if it does exist, that it's public -- in any given class.  You really just have to read the source for the class you're interested in.

I will say that in the widely-used [JavaBean convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean), classes that could reasonably have a length attribute but don't have a public variable `length` often have `getLength()` and `setLength()` methods.  That's better than a public variable for a number of reasons that are kind of out of scope for your question, but if you're interested, check out [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374988/purpose-of-private-members-in-a-class/2375022#2375022).

Comment: Yes its the length property of arrays could you please tell where it actually is defined?

Answer (score 0):

Its a variable that can be accessed for an array to find out how many elements there are in the array.