# Java System.out.format with double array

Tags: java, printf

I am trying to output information with System.out.format using a double[] array as the argument. This does not work:

```
out.format("New dimensions:\n" +
        "Length: %f\n" +
        "Width: %f\n\n",
        doubleArray);
```

This, however, does:

```
out.format("New dimensions:\n" +
        "Length: %f\n" +
        "Width: %f\n\n",
        doubleArray[0], doubleArray[1]);
```

Why doesn't the first format work? It supposedly works with strings just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java will autobox your `double` to a `Double`, but it won't autobox your `double[]` to a `Double[]`, so it doesn't match `Object[]`. As a result, instead of being unpacked into the `Object...` varargs, your array is being treated as the array itself -- which, obviously, can't be formatted as a double.

If you declare your array as `Double[]` instead of `double[]`, the call to `format` works.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed the type to `Double[]` and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because an array isn't a double(in Java an array is a class, so it's like a general pointer here). You need to specify *exactly* what will be outputted, and you did - it's the `%f` [format specifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string). ArraySomething[] doesn't match..

See here for more on [Java's Formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) and here - [How does array class work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910774/how-does-array-class-work-in-java) ,  for  Java arrays.

Comment: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) "The syntax for these two java.io.PrintStream methods is the same: public PrintStream format(String format, Object... args)" The three dots operator is supposed to optionally take an array of arguments, but it's not working here. I get an conversion error.