# The class type dynamically assigned to the variable

Tags: java, compilation

I'm wrapping an Axis web service in a Springboot microservice and stumbled on some code that does not make sense.

```
Class cls = AmountInfo[].class;
```

What class is returned above ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does array class work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910774/how-does-array-class-work-in-java)

Comment: That's what would be called the `AmountInfo` *array* class, and that's different from the class of `AmountInfo`

Comment: By the way `int.class` is an other exotic class.

Comment: "What class is returned above" - why did not you call "System.out.println(cls.getName())"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the docs of `java.lang.Class` have to say about this:

> Every array also belongs to a class that is reflected as a Class object that is shared by all arrays with the same element type and number of dimensions.

Just as the a `Class` object for the type `AmountInfo`, there is a `Class` for the array 1D array type `AmountInfo[]`, just as there is also a type for the 2D array type `AmountInfo[][]`, etc.

A `Class` of an array type returns `true` when `isArray()` is invoked on it. `AmountInfo[].class` is equivalent to `AmountInfo.class.arrayType()`. And you can use it with the reflection API the same way you can use a normal class (example below):

```
//Creating a 1D array of AmountInfo type
jshell> Array.newInstance(AmountInfo.class, 2)
$65 ==> AmountInfo[2] { null, null }

// Creating a 2D array of AmountInfo type
jshell> Array.newInstance(AmountInfo[].class, 2)
$66 ==> AmountInfo[2][] { null, null }
```